# HTML communication issue: jQuery .load function doesn't seem working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, load

I'm actually working on a group project in my highschool (So I'm not a real developper) and I have to create a website that'll display some datas off of a web server my Arduino card created (just a html page). I looked 8 weeks for a solution through internet and I definetely didn't find anything, I have 1 week to finish this, I'm desperate..

I have learned HTML and CSS, a little bit of javascript and jQuery. And all my operations are made in a local environnement.

First, I tried to get the value by opening the web server in a new window -> taking the wanted value -> closing the window using :

```
<script>
 function myFunction() {
 var myWindow = window.open("http://192.168.137.201/", "", "width=1","height=1");
  var x = myWindow.document.getElementById("temp").innerHTML;
  document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = x;
  myWindow.close();
}
```

So basically I'm trying to output the value with "temp" id from the webserver in the paragraph with "content" value. Here is how my server looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8"/>
 </head>
 <body>
 <p id="temp">-1</p><br />
 <p id="cod">-90</p><br />
 <p id="partic">0</p><br />
 <p id="anemo">14</p><br />
 </body>
 </html>
```

Replace the text in this paragraph.

```
<p id="content">En attente de donnée(Waiting for data)</p>
<button id="btn">Mettre à jour(Update)</button>
```

The script was working whenever I clicked the button below the paragraph. The window was opening then closing but the paragraph wasn't changing or became blank.

Later I discovered jQuery and found it more useful because it changes the value without opening a window. I used the .load fonction exactly as it was used on w3schools website but it still won't work.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#btn").click(function(){
        $("#content").load("http://192.168.137.201/ #temp");
     });
   });
 </script>
```

I used google CDN in this example but I tried with Microsoft's one and a local downloaded one.

As I said I looked for a long time and tried different methods, checked if I didn't miss any code key such as ".innerHTML" and others.
I also have Xbee modules not working and I have to find a solution to this issue also so you understand that I can't spend more time searching.

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: You cannot use ajax (`load()` method here) for cross domain request if server doesn't specifically allow it

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes and I found out that I didn't declared the encoding method (on my server) I fixed it and still nothing work. The console shows no errors either on my website or webserver, it loads correctly the jquery code file (as I click on the link it appears clearly in my browser).

Comment: @A.Wolff How do I know if the server allow it ?